# Arithmetic with functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to write a function that solves the following math problem:  3625 * 9824 + 777, using *only* two functions:  "add" and "multiply". I am stuck here:

```
var multiply = function (number) {
  return * 9824;
};
```

Comment: I'm stuck too.  What is your question, or what do you need help with?

Comment: I'd suggest not to hardcode one of the operand. You may want to try the more generic `var multiply = function(a, b) { return a * b; }`. Usage : `var c = multiply(3625, 9824);`

Comment: You could start off with [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Defining_functions). Take a look at the example for `square`. After you get done with this one, it would probably be helpful to go through the other tutorials in this guide.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the function's argument (`number`) to "tell" javascript what you're multiplying:

```
var multiply = function (number) {
    return number * 9824;
    // Here^
};
```

Comment: Just like in math: `f(x) = x * 9824` becomes `function f(x) {return x*9824}`

Answer (score 0):

Good start.

Remember that the function *parameter* (in this case, `number`) can be used as a variable inside the function itself. In your case, you want to multiply whatever `number` is passed in and return the result. So what you'd be looking for here is:

```
var multiply = function(num) {
  return num * 9842;
}
```

:) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

first create your functions:

```
function add(a, b){
   return a+b;
}

function multiply(a,b){
   return a*b;
}
```

then you can call them...

```
let ans = 0;
ans = multiply(3625, 9824);
ans = sum(ans, 777);
console.log("3625 * 9824 + 777 = ",ans);
```

Keep going :) and this apply to all functional languages :D

Answer (score 0):

```
function add(a,b)
{
   return (parseInt(a)+parseInt(b));
}

function multiply(a,b)
{
   return (parseInt(a)*parseInt(b));
}

var result = add(mutiply(3625,9824),777);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function add(a, b) {
   return a + b;
};
var resultAdd = add(9824, 777);

function multiply(a, b) {
   return a * b;
};
var result = multiply(resultAdd, 36325);
```